# How do I create or mimic SQL Server Management Studio query results report

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, enterprise-library

In SQL Server management studio, you can output a queries result to a grid (the default setting) such that when you run the query, the query results show up directly underneath it. Alternatively, you can output the query results to a file, which generates an .RPT file wherever you like.

[image: sql server results to file]

The report file looks something like this (when opened in notepad);

[image: report file]

My question is, how do I create the same type of file (the same file format, spacing and all) in .NET (I am using VB.Net).

This is what I have thus far, using enterprise libraries, but it returns a dataset, from which I extract a dataview. I can convert the dataview to the text file, but that text file doesnt look anything like this report file, of which I don't even know how its formatting is decided.

`Dim dbCommandWrapper As DBCommandWrapper

```
            dbCommandWrapper = GlobalDatabase.objDatabase.GetStoredProcCommandWrapper("My_StoredProcedure_Report")

            If IsNothing(objGlobalDatabase.objTransaction) Then
                Return GlobalDatabase.objDatabase.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommandWrapper).Tables(0).DefaultView()
            Else
                Return GlobalDatabase.objDatabase.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommandWrapper, objGlobalDatabase.objTransaction).Tables(0).DefaultView()
            End If`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Management result view is nothing more than a formatted text. You need to receive `DataTable`, then

```vb
dim columns as new Dictionary(of int, int) ' save col index / col width info
for i as integer = 0 to DataTable.Columns.count - 1
    columns.Add(i, 1)
next

dim data as new List(of List(of string))

' preload you values and calculate width
For rows as int = 0 to DataTable.Rows.Count-1

    for cols as integer = 0 to DataTable.Columns.Count - 1

        dim cl as new List(of string) ' Save your string values here
        if not isDbnull(DataTable.Rows(rows)(cols)) Then
            dim val as string = convert.toString()(DataTable.Rows(rows)(cols))
            if val.Length > columns(cols) Then 
                columns(cols) = val.Length 
            end if
            cl.Add(val)
        else
            cl.Add(string.empty)
        end if    
    next
    data.Add(cl)
next
```

Now, print your output

```vb
dim sb as new StringBuilder()

' Do the header
for i as integer = 0 to Datatable.Columns.count -1
    sb.Append(Datatable.Columns(i).ColumnName.PadRight(columns(i), "_"))
    sb.Append(" ") ' space between columns 
next
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine)

' Now Data
for each l as list(of list(of string)) in data
    for i as integer = 0 to l.count
        sb.Append(l(i).Padright(columns(i)))
        sb.Append(" ") ' space between columns 
    next
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine)
next
```

Now you have the `sb` object with the data. What you need now is to display it using some font in which each character takes up same width, for example `Courier New`

Warning: code typed from memory and nit checked but should represent what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, it appears that the report generated by sql server management studio sets column width based on the maximum size of the database columns, rather the longest element retrieved in that column. Furthermore, this is true only when that length is longer then the length of the column name header. Given those two things, how would I go about setting the column size appropriately?

Comment: @n00b using code I provided it is easy to variate the output. You can use ado.net to load your dataTable in 2 stages - first, schema; second, data. Then, instead of `...ColumnName.PadRight(columns(i), "_")` you can set header as `...ColumnName.PadRightdt(Datatable.Columns(i).MaxLength, "_")` for strings. And for numbers you can use fixrd width or get it out of datatype `...ColumnName.PadRightdt(int.MaxValue.ToString(), "_")`. You can get this info from INFORMATION_SCHEMA if you want to. My code is to show you the way but you have to take care of the details you want to have. Plug in anything

Comment: Thank you, your answer gets me half way there, but it is still not the same format as a SQL Server "results to file" file. I need the file to match the format of the stored procedure schema. +1 for your help. Please see my follow up question on how to obtain the schema using enterprise libraries http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939841/how-to-obtain-the-database-schema-of-a-stored-procedure